# DialogButtonBox buttons appear stacked

Tags: qt, popup, qml

I am attempting to customize the text on the buttons of my custom Dialog.

For this I used a DialogButtonBox as the footer of the dialog, together with some loaders that will load the appropriate buttons as chosen by the user.

However what I'm seeing is that for some popups the buttons get stacked at the far left, and you can't click them. I have managed to reproduce it with a small example:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Row{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Button{

            property var popup: SimDialog { }

            onClicked:
            {
                popup.open()
            }

            text: "Open"
        }
    }

}
```

SimDialog.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Dialog {
    // ID
    id: popupRoot

    width: 500
    height: 200

    topMargin: 20
    bottomMargin: 10
    leftMargin: 20
    rightMargin: 10
    // Centered position
    x: parent ? parent.x + (parent.width / 2) - (width / 2)   : 0// align horizontally centered
    y: parent ? parent.y + (parent.height / 2) - (height / 2) : 0// align vertically centered

    modal: true
    focus: true
    clip: true

    property int buttons: Dialog.Close | Dialog.Ignore

    title: "Test"
    Button
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "HELLO"
    }


    // personalized dialog box buttons so we can translate the button text.
    footer: DialogButtonBox {
        id: dialogBox
        alignment: Qt.AlignRight

        Loader
        {
            active: buttons & Dialog.Help
            sourceComponent:
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Help")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.HelpRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }

        Loader
        {
            active: buttons & Dialog.Discard
            sourceComponent:
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Continue without saving")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.DestructiveRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }

        Loader
        {
            active: buttons & Dialog.Save
            sourceComponent: 
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Save")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.AcceptRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }

        Loader
        {
            active: buttons & Dialog.Ignore
            sourceComponent: 
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Ignore")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.RejectRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }

        Loader
        {
            active:  buttons & Dialog.Apply
            sourceComponent: 
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Apply")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.AcceptRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }

        Loader
        {
            active: buttons & Dialog.Ok
            sourceComponent:
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Ok")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.AcceptRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }

        Loader
        {
            active: buttons & Dialog.Close
            sourceComponent: 
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Close")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.RejectRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }

        Loader
        {
            active: buttons & Dialog.Cancel
            sourceComponent:
                Button {
                    parent: dialogBox
                    text: qsTr("Cancel")
                    DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.RejectRole
                    flat: true
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in my actual application I have several of these popups and only some of them have this behavior. I haven't been able to pinpoint a commonality between those that don't work either, so I'm really lost.

Here's how it looks on my end 
[image]

Comment: I see at least a large number of unnecessary components. You can put only one loader and set of Components and so assign a suitable component according to `button`. Also you can replace `sourceComponent: Component { Button {}}` with `sourceComponent: Button {}` since the `Button` is already a component. As for me te problem is that Loader has no size. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loader-sizing-behavior) for more info.

Comment: The link says `If an explicit size is not specified for the Loader, the Loader is automatically resized to the size of the loaded item once the component is loaded.` which is what I want. Buttons have an implicit size based on their text. Giving the buttons or loader an explicit size does nothing. 
As for changing to `sourceComponent: Button{}`, thanks, I have done that (and edited my question)
I don't necessarily understand what you mean by assigning a suitable component, as I don't know beforehand which buttons will be showing for each dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need the loaders. You can just use the visible property in Button. 
This worked for me as expected:

```
// personalized dialog box buttons so we can translate the button text.
    footer: DialogButtonBox {
        id: dialogBox

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Help")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.HelpRole
            flat: true
            visible: true //false
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Continue without saving")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.DestructiveRole
            flat: true
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Save")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.AcceptRole
            flat: true
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Ignore")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.RejectRole
            flat: true
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Apply")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.AcceptRole
            flat: true
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Ok")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.AcceptRole
            flat: true
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Close")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.RejectRole
            flat: true
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Cancel")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.RejectRole
            flat: true
        }
    }
```

Comment: This indeed works but the buttons are not aligned to the right, as I want them. Depending on which ones are showing, they are on their respective positions, which looks awkward. Adding the property `alignment: Qt.AlignRight` does nothing
[Here's an example of what I get vs what I want](https://imgur.com/a/KWmSrEO)

Comment: I know I don't need the Loaders, but my application will have several of these popups and I'd rather not instantiate extra visual items as the start up is already quite slow.

Comment: it looks like Qt.AlignRight is working as expected only when using standardButtons: DialogButtonBox.Ok | DialogButtonBox.Cancel , but not when defining custom buttons. I guess it is a bug!